# Run to cursor in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I can not see the Run To Cursor in VS 2012 when I am developing in C#. I checked the tool bar and also DEBUG menu and in both places there is no such entry. Where can I find this option.

Comment: did you check Context menu on code , I always use that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+F10.  Otherwise you can right click on the line you want to run to and select Run to cursor.

You can add the button to the toolbar by selecting Add or Remove buttons on the Debug toolbar and then selecting Customize.

Comment: Thanks, How can I add it to toolbar?